# Detecting battery degradation in voltage profile.

Tags: voltage, batteries

I'm measuring the voltage of a battery and a capacitor over time. Both components are charged and discharged daily. I don't have a background in electronics. When the components eventually begin to degrade or fail would this be visible in the voltage profile? Thanks

Comment: Yes, if your measurement is sufficiently sensitive, which it might not be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are lucky and the discharge profile is more or less constant, than yes for battery and maybe for capacitor. Just note that the measurement is not just voltage, it's voltage at certain time. Best is to build a table. In any case i would suggest to charge and discharge ten batteries for however many times it takes. Then it's possible to know the exact parameters to measure.

By the way, one way is to count discharge cycles. It's easier and for most cases efficient enough.

Comment: This is hand waving, not an answer.   "If you are lucky... ", well then how would one know if he got lucky or not. Any criteria mentioned in the answer? Nope. In addition, it isn't even known what battery chemistry the O.P. is talking about.  The question is not too sharp either.